# What is the name of a human-inspired machine learning approach?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, training, terminology, hebbian-learning

I once came across a neural network being trained without back-propagation or genetic algorithms (or using any kind of data sets). It was based on how the human brain learns and adjusts its connections between neurons.

What is the name of such a machine learning approach?

Answer (score 6):

If it was based on how the human brain learns, it might have used [hebbian learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebbian_theory).

One example for such a network would be [HTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_temporal_memory).

Comment: Jeff Hawkin's book, *On Intelligence*, describes HTM generally.

Answer (score 4):

There are approaches to training neural networks that do not use back-propagation, or genetic algorithms. One example is the [Extreme Learning Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_learning_machine) approach.

You may find something useful in this [older discussion on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235862/is-it-possible-to-train-a-neural-network-without-backpropagation).

Comment: What approach does ELM then use? I think it would be useful to say something about it.